# How to implement constraints to minimize waste in order production

Tags: optaplanner

I have this entity

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Machine {

    private int m_id;
    private String m_name;
    private int m_workingTimePerPiece;
    private float m_wastePercentage;

    private List<Order> m_plannedOrders;
...
    @PlanningListVariable
    public List<Order> getPlannedOrders() {
        return m_plannedOrders;
    }

    public void setPlannedOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        m_plannedOrders = orders;
    }
}
```

This fact

```
public class Order {

    private Long m_id;
    private String m_name;
    private int m_orderSize;
    ....
}
```

This planning solution

```
@PlanningSolution
public class MachineOrdersPlanning {

    private List<Machine> m_machines;
    private List<Order> m_orders;
    private HardSoftScore m_score;
    
    public MachineOrdersPlanning(){}

    public MachineOrdersPlanning(List<Machine> machines, List<Order> orders) {
        m_machines = machines;
        m_orders = orders;
    }

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public List<Machine> getMachines() {
        return m_machines;
    }

    @ValueRangeProvider
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return m_orders;
    }

    @PlanningScore
    public HardSoftScore getScore() {
        return m_score;
    }

    public void setScore(HardSoftScore score) {
        m_score = score;
    }
}
```

And the solver

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Build the solver
        SolverFactory<MachineOrdersPlanning> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
                .withSolutionClass(MachineOrdersPlanning.class)
                .withEntityClasses(Machine.class)
                .withConstraintProviderClass(MachineOrdersConstraintProvider.class)
                .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofMillis(500)));
        Solver<MachineOrdersPlanning> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

        // Load the problem
        MachineOrdersPlanning problem = getInputData();

        // Solve the problem
        MachineOrdersPlanning solution = solver.solve(problem);

        printSolution(solution);
    }
```

Each machine can handle a list of orders based on an order.itemCode.
The same item code could be worked in multiple machine.
Each machine has its own waste percent in working order piece and has its own time to work one order piece.

I successfully created a constraint to put the correct order in the correct machine.

```
    Constraint machineContainsManageableOrders(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
                .forEach(Machine.class)
                .filter(machine -> !machine.checkPlannedOrdersCode())
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD).asConstraint("Machine schedule only manageable orders");
    }
```

Now for example, if Machine1 has waste 1% and time for 1 piece 1min and Machine2 has waste 5% and time for 1 piece 20sec.
How can I create a constraint that minimize the waste and minimize the work time.
So, I mean, I cannot put all orders in machine1 with waste 1% because maximize the work time.

Thank you.
S.